# Android: Align text in center of spinner

Tags: android, alignment, spinner

Maybe you will see something that i didn't. I don't understand why it refuses to align. I have 2 spinners in layout and tried to align text to center.
In both spinners, the text is aligned to the left. 
Here is the code.

Xml code :

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="36dp"
       android:background="@color/orange"
       android:gravity="bottom|center_vertical" >

       <Spinner
           android:id="@+id/sub_from_category"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_weight="2"
           android:layout_height="35dp"
           android:background="@drawable/spinners" />

       <View
           android:layout_width="2dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="0"
           android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
           android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

       <Spinner
           android:id="@+id/sub_to_category"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_weight="2"  
           android:layout_height="35dp"
           android:background="@drawable/spinners" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

xml code :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#454545"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:textSize="1/>
```

And Java Activity :

```
subFromCategory = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sub_from_category);
        subToCategory = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sub_to_category);


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterF = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Angle);
        adapterF.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sub_spinner);
        subFromCategory.setAdapter(adapterF);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterT = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Angle);
        adapterT.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sub_spinner);
        subToCategory.setAdapter(adapterT);
```

Thank you,
Niro

Comment: check this answer...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511049/set-view-text-align-at-center-in-spinner-in-android

Comment: Thanks for reply . Iv'e already visited there.

Answer (score 1):

Always remember this :

**`layout gravity`** - a property which specifies the 'gravity' of an *object **itself***, in its parent view.

***gravity*** - a property which specifies the 'gravity' of *the **subviews*** inside the object.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've tried it in so many way. When i did the separate xml for spinner it worked good for a single spinner in line, But the problem is that it won't align to the middle when there is 2 spinners in the same line.

Comment: the gravity and layout gravity do not work properly with the Spinner.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and solution was "simple". You must have "space" for set it in the center.

Wrong:

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Right:

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```