# How can I align text of the spinner to the centre?

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is my XML of the spinner but it did not work.

```
  <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/frequency"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_voices"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
         />
```

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/7511272/1457952

Comment: this is text view and i am using the spinner i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your own layout for spinner item.

```
ArrayAdapter adap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, new String[]{"ABC", "DEF", "GHI"});
spriner.setAdapter(adap);
```

Where R.layout.spinner_item is a layout with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: Thnx, but this is text view and i am using the spinner i think, i am new to android plz help

Comment: First of all create one layout for textview and set into arrayAdapter and then set that adapter in spinner.